# Load balancing titan nodes

Tags: load-balancing, titan

Let's say I have a Titan cluster with Cassandra as storage backend and an application that talks with RexPro (or the new Gremlin Server). How should I distribute the queries from my applications to the Titan nodes without knowing which node actually holds the data?
Is a simple round-robin a good choice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a really large graph, round-robin isn't the best option, but there really aren't other strategies ready for use I'm afraid.  Experiments were done with more advanced query routing with reasonable success, but none have made it to production Titan/TinkerPop yet.

Comment: Thanks, are there any resources where I can find information like that? I am also searching for information about hardware requirements / recommendations for Titan for example. I think that it would be really nice to have some kind of 'best practices' and / or 'anti-patterns' for Titan to allow beginners to learn from the experience of others.

Comment: I would start with the aurelius blog posts - http://thinkaurelius.com/blog/ - some of the code examples are out of date with the latest version, but the concepts are generally still valid.